# Updating table column based on best matching results on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, join

I have a lookup table, **names**, with name and gender columns. The gender column can have values as {Male, female, unknown, -1}. 
There is yet another **customer** table that has some names. It also has a gender column that has to be updated by looking up the 'name' column of *names* table. Only the genders that match with value=Male or Female need to be picked. For unknown and -1 , I set gender=NULL.

The 'name' from the *customer* table may or may not match exactly with the names in *names*. I am able to update the genders based on the exactly matching names. However, for the not exactly matching names, I want to do a best match lookup and then update it. Is this possible using a query?

Below is the query that I used to get the exact matching names:

```
update customer
 inner join names ON (customer.name= names.name)
 set gender= names.gender
where gender in ('Male','Female');
```

Comment: I don't think regex are suitable for that. Have a look at the Hamming distance. If you are cleaning up or merging databases it is often a lot easier to implement it in Java or a similar language than using PL/SQL.

Comment: You _may_ try the [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function of MySQL, but I don't think it will work well with names. In addition to @maraca 's suggestion of Hamming distance you may have a look at the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Btw: a surprisingly good guess is: If the name ends in "a", then it's female.

Comment: You probably need to look for an exact match, fixing the data in the lookup table as you encounter it.  There are numerous names in English that are "very close" but suggest different genders in general:  Alex and Alexa, Bill and Billie, Carl and Carol, Dan and Dana, Evan and Eva, Frank and Fran, and I'm only up to "F".  These all have a Levenshtein distance of 1 and many examples probably have the same soundex as well.

Comment: Right, but to do an approximate near match using `LIKE %Bill%` (for eg.,) , how can we form the query like I gave above? i.e., in my inner join i gave `inner join names ON (customer.name= names.name)`. How can we do a LIKE in this?